# Is it necessary to use JADE when building Angular Apps with Node and Express?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

Is it possible to build angularJS apps with plain HTML, ExpressJS on NodeJS ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No** it is not necessary, you can use different templating engines with Node & Express or you can just send pure HTML files.

Jade is just a default templating engine that comes with Express.js, If you want a templating engine that is close to bare html i think dust.js is a good one.

Quite frankly angular.js has nothing to do with this.

You can set up express to render pure html files like this.

```
app.configure(function(){

  app.set("view options", {
     layout: false
  });

  app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(string, options){
      return function(locals){
        return string;
      };
    }
  });

});
```

Then just render like this

```
app.get('/myUrl', function(request, response){
  response.render("index.html");
});
```

or, when I was using ember on the frontend it was so conflicting to write handlebars templates in jade templates, so in my jade template I simply included a pure html file like this.

```
include '/handlebars/templates.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Jade is a (primarily – and I imagine it’s how you’re using it) server-side template engine. Angular bases itself off the HTML served to the client; it doesn’t matter what produced it. NodeJS is just a server. Express is just a server-side framework.

Angular can even work without a server; see jsFiddle, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) is another framework that is popular with express and is pretty close to just bare HTML.

Comment: I basically just want to use plain HTML so I can focus all my learning in NodeJS without worrying to learn one more templating language at the same time.

Comment: Understandable, though I do recommend using Jade eventually. It's really not very difficult and it's so much easier to look at. However, EJS is probably the most popular (at least from what I have seen) template engine that is really close to bare HTML.